# Scala try and catch Error

Tags: scala, try-catch

So here is my code:

```
def loadOperation(fileName:String): csvList = {
  try{
   val pattern = """^(.+);(\d{5});(4|2|31);(0|1);(.+);(\d+|\d+,\d+)$""".r
   Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines().foldLeft(List[CsvEntry]())((csvList, currentLine) =>
     currentLine match {
      case pattern(organisation,yearAndQuartal,medKF,trueOrFalse,name,money) => new CsvEntry(organisation,yearAndQuartal.toInt,medKF.toInt,trueOrFalse.toInt,name,money) :: csvList
      case default => csvList
      })
  } catch {
    case one: java.io.FileNotFoundException => println("This file could not be found!")
  }}
```

The problem is that my code doesnt work, it always shows the following error:

> type mismatch found: Unit required csvList which expands to List[CsvEntry]?

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: What's the definition of `cvsList`? You have it as the function return type but then you also use it as a value in the default case

Comment: ups sorry: "type csvList = CsvList[Entry]"
"val list: csvList = List()"

Comment: When you catch the `FileNotFoundException` you use `println` to print out an error message. As a consequence the type will be `Unit`.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, you're using it as a value, as an argument to foldLeft and the returned value of the expression in the default case. Is there some instance also named csvList in scope?

Comment: yeah i have definded an emptyList, then i am catching things from a an inputfile with my regex and adding it to my csvList....so I am adding CsvEntries to my csvList. Wheres the problem?

Comment: should it not work if I simply add " ; Nil" after the println case statement?

Comment: Might be worth looking into returning and using `scala.util.Try`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `catch` clause:

```
println("This file could not be found!")
```

has the type `Unit`, which is obviously not a `csvList`. You should add an additional line that returns an empty list, such as

```
catch {
    case one: java.io.FileNotFoundException => println("This file could not be found!")
}

Nil
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it also possible to return the list? But in this case I think Nil is the better solution!

Comment: Do you mean the list from `foldLeft`? In case a FNFE occurs, it won't even reach the `foldLeft` part, so `Nil` is fine here.